# htaccess redirect cause error 500

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I want to remove extension from request and add it on the server side, so I wrote this code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This code work great in standard use. For example if I have file in `HOME/foo/bar.php`
and I request it like `localhost/foo/bar`, the code is working and redirect me to the correct file.

But if my request is `localhost/foo/bar/` (backslash at the end), or `localhost/foo/bar/a`
I got internal server error (500), and in the log file I got `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects`.

I have been tested the code and saw that the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` ignores the wrong suffix of the request `/a` so it see only `HOME/foo/bar`, but the RewriteRule `$1` dose not ignore it.

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This takes care of trailing slash issue as well as making sure correct php file exists before rewriting.